# Why does this type need explicit cast?

Tags: java, generics, casting, kotlin

I've created an extension function to JavaFX TableColumn that makes it more concise to implement a cellFactory without the repetetive boilerplate. The extension function is defined like this:

```
inline fun <S, T> TableColumn<S, T>.cellFormat(crossinline formatter: (TableCell<S, T>.(T) -> Unit)) {
    cellFactory = Callback { column: TableColumn<S, T> ->
        object : TableCell<S, T>() {
            override fun updateItem(item: T, empty: Boolean) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty)

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    text = null
                    graphic = null
                } else {
                    formatter(this, item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To format a TableCell I only need to define what should happen in TableCell.updateItem when there is a non-null item available for the current cell. To format a LocalDateTime for example, I can now write:

```
column.cellFormat { text = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(it) }
```

I then went on to define another extension that does just this, so I can just write:

```
column.formatAsDateTime()
```

This function uses the first function, like this:

```
fun <S, LocalDateTime> TableColumn<S, LocalDateTime>.formatAsDateTime() =
    cellFormat { value ->
        text = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(value as TemporalAccessor)
    }
```

My question is why I have to cast the LocalDateTime to TemporalAccessor?

My first attempt was:

```
text = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(value)
```

The compiler complains:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is LocalDateTime but java.time.TemporalAccessor! was expected

Granted, the DateTimeFormatter#format function takes a TemporalAccessor, not a LocalDateTime, but LocalDateTime does indeed implement TemporalAccessor (via Temporal).

The cast to TemporalAccessor is only needed in the formatAsDateTime extension function, not when using cellFormat directly from the call site.

Shouldn't Kotlin be able to perform this smart cast automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out, newbie mistake. The LocalDateTime type parameter is just an alias. The correct declaration would be:

```
fun <S> TableColumn<S, LocalDateTime>.formatAsDateTime() =
    cellFormat { text = dateTimeFormatter.format(it) }
```

Comment: shouldn't the compiler complain that a type parameter shadowed `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: It doesn't, but I don't think that happens in Java either. My class didn't even have an import for java.time.LocalDateTime, so there was really no way the compiler could know that. However, even with an import it doesn't complain.

Comment: would you care fill a feature request for such a warning? It could save someone quite a time

Comment: I'm thinking that there must be a reason why this isn't implemented in javac already. Most of the time, you might not have an import, so the use case is pretty slim I think.